# Prove distribution of or over implies knowing the implication is always true

Tags: logic, formal-proofs, sequent-calculus, hilbert-calculus

I was given a task to construct a Hilbert-style proof for the following:

$A → B ⊢ C ∨ A → C ∨ B$

I figured I could use the axiom $A→B≡A∨B≡B$, but this leads me nowhere since I don't think I can use the consequent anywhere.

The theorem is intuitively true to me (since we know $A→B$, adding a true $C$ in there will give $⊤→⊤$, obviously true, and a false $C$ gives the original $A→B$), but I do not know how to prove this.

I'm using Tourlakis' Mathematical Logic and all axioms contained within it.

Comment: What you're doing there $A→B≡A∨B≡B$ is neither hilbert-caluclus nor sequent-calculus ... .  If you want help on this one, you'll first have to tell us exactly what rules you have to work with, because there are *many* logical proof systems.

Comment: I am using Tourlakis' Mathematical Logic (2008) and the axioms contained within it.

Comment: Which doesn't help anyone who doesn't have that book on hand.

Comment: Looked at that book ... ugh, that's not a very user-friendly system for beginners. Do you have to use that book?

Comment: Yeah, it's what the class is using @Bram28

Comment: @Bill But have you had any exposure to formal proof systems at all? Like I said, this is far feom the easiest system to work with, and the book has very few examples which doesn't help either. Is being able to do these formal proofs a big part of the course?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant Hilbert Axiom Schemas...(your book may label them differently, or treat disjunction as a substitution.)

$$\begin{array}{rl}\mathrm A2.&\phi\to(\psi\to\phi)
\\ \mathrm A3.&(\phi\to(\psi\to\xi))\to((\phi\to\psi)\to(\phi\to\xi))
\\ \lor\mathrm {IL}.&\phi\to(\phi\lor\psi)
\\ \lor\mathrm {IR}.&\phi\to(\psi\lor\phi)
\\ \lor\mathrm E.&(\phi\to\xi)\to((\phi\to\xi)\to((\phi\lor\psi)\to\xi))
\\\hdashline \mathrm P1.&A\to B
\\\hline 2.&\lower{2ex}\ddots\end{array}$$

Comment: Unfortunately, Tourlakis' axioms look nothing like this ....

Answer (score 0):

1) $A \to B \ \ \ \ \ \langle \text { assumption } \rangle$

2) $ C \lor A \ \ \ \ \ \ \langle \text { assumption } \rangle$

3) $C \lor A \equiv \lnot C \to A \ \ \ \ \langle 2.4.11 \rangle$

4) $\lnot C \to A \ \ \ \ \langle (2,3) + \text {Eqn} \rangle$

5) $\lnot C \to B \ \ \ \ \langle (2.5.9 \text { Coroll. - Transitivity of} \to) \rangle$

6) $C \lor B \equiv \lnot C \to B \ \ \ \ \langle 2.4.11 \rangle$

7) $C \lor B \ \ \ \ \langle (5,6) + \text {Eqn} \rangle$

> 8) $C \lor A \to C \lor B \ \ \ \langle (2.6.1 \text { Deduction Theorem}) \rangle$